# How to use while IFS=, to read a field from the file and then subsequently replace this field as well

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, sed

```
while IFS=, read -r Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4; do #Reading from a CSV file
Replace Q2 with the string "Nan"    #Replace the second comma separated value with a string
```

I am looking for how to do this second line where this second value read from the file is then replaced with a string and it changes the actual file itself rather than just replacing the variable. I figure I will be using sed -i but not sure exactly what the easier way to do this would be without specifically writing to the file again.

Comment: Sed will loop over lines itself - there's rarely a good reason to wrap a sed command in a shell loop in this way. For simple comma delimited data you could use something like `sed 's/,[^,]*/,Nan/'` for example. Or to handle the nuances of CSV something like `mlr --csv put '$[ [[2]] ] = "Nan"'` in Miller.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. Could you explain the line why you have ,[^,]* ? This looks for an expression beginning with any number of commas, but why is that first comma there in front of it though?

Comment: `,[^,]*` is a regular expression that matches a comma followed by zero or more non-commas. The *first* instance of this pattern will correspond to the delimiter plus the *second* field.

Answer (score 2):

For file with a simple format with delimiters, awk is often handy.

E.g. given the input file `foo.txt`, this would change the second comma-separated field on every line, keep the rest intact and print the modified file out.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ $2 = "Nan"; print }' < foo.txt
a,Nan,c,d
e,Nan,g,h
```

`-v FS=,` and `-v OFS=,` set the input and output field separators to the comma, and `$2 = ...` modifies the second field on the line. If you want to make the change on all lines, you can remove the `NR == 2` test.

In case you need to do that on just one line, e.g. line 123, you could do:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, -v line=123 'NR == line { $2 = "Nan" } { print }' < foo.txt
```

Note that I said, "simple format", if it's one of those "comma-separated" formats where quoted commas can appear in the data, then awk is not your tool.

Comment: Thanks. To  be clear, in the pseudocode I provided, this means I would replace the NR==2 with NR=Current_Line_Number_Of_File, correct (Assuming I want to do it line by line instead of the whole file at once.

Comment: @Prospero, if you want to do it for all lines, just do `awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ $2 = "Nan" } { print }' < foo.txt` Usually, doing stuff line-by-line is a bit silly, it's slowww if you start a full awk or sed or whatever process for each line. I think I misread your question and thought you wanted to change just one line.

Answer (score 1):

In plain bash, you could do this (it's both slow and non-aware of CSV-specifics)

```bsh
while IFS=, read -r q1 q2 q3 q4; do
    echo "$q1,NaN,$q3,$q4"
done < inputFile > outputFile

ln inputFile inputFile.bak   # backup input file
mv outputFile inputFile      # overwrite input file
```

With other tools, you gain performance and safety:

```bsh
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| row[1] = "NaN"; puts CSV.generate_line row}
' infile > outfile
```